# How to create Task ( project.task ) under specific customer (res.partner ) in ODOOERP

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am using below code to relate suitable company or contacts while creating task,but fails .
Please help me in this.

```
$result = $models->execute_kw(
    $db, 
    $uid, 
    $password,
    'project.task', 
    'create',
    array(
        array('name'=>"Subject line for task"),
        array('partner_id.id'=>"32"),
        array('partner_id.name', '=', 'Asuzz'),
    ));
```

Can anybody know what kind of changes i have to made.

your help is really appreciates.

Comment: I have tried with : 
 $id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
    'project.task', 'create',
    array(
 
 array('name'=>"Subject for task"),
 array('partner_id'=>32),
 )
 );


But still its not relating with respective customer in odoo.
Really Stuck!!!

Comment: Do you have any error message to show us? I'm not familiar with php but maybe I'm able to help you

Comment: Thats the actual problem i am facing . " No ERROR" and still task is creating in ODOO CRM.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to tell Odoo the partner ID. The name isn't needed.

```
array('partner_id'=>32)
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply.
I have tried with 

$id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
    'project.task', 'create',
    array(
 
 array('name'=>"subject for task"),
 array('partner_id'=>32),
 
 //array('partner_id.name', '=', '6'),
 )
 );

But still its relating with suitable customer...!!!
Stuck!!!

Comment: Not really, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to Odoo 10 it's working for me.
{
//Creating task

```
$id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
    'project.task', 'create',
    array(array('name'=>"new task",'project_id'=>7)));
```

}